# Is there something better than using isTrusted to register a click on a Javascript animation?

Tags: javascript, animation

I am making a game where I want to add to a score when a user clicks an element. If the element is static, clicking adds one to the score, but when I add it to a JS animation, there is no predicting how many clicks register as true. (Game at: https://hmcka.github.io/100days/day38/day38.html) Is this happening because I am trying to have the click happen on an animation? Is there a better way to collect a click on animation? I thought about inserting a setTimeout to add a pause after the initial click, but I think that this would be problematic if the user decides to click quickly several times. The code I used for this feature is below.

```
    function bonk(e) {
        if(!e.isTrusted) return;
        score ++;
        scoreBoard.textContent = score;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventObject.isTrusted` tests to see if the user generated the action or code was written that did the action. That's all it does. Client-side code can always be altered, so it doesn't actually prevent anything. It's just a way for your code to tell the difference.

I believe the problem with your score being so high has to do with your animation. Elements are overlapping each other, so technically you are clicking on Elements below the one you're clicking on. You need to make sure they are hitting the actual target, like:

```
function bonk(e){
  if(e.target === this){
    scoreBoard.textContent = ++score;
  }
}
```

After you do that, change your animation.

PS
Although it won't kill your code, it looks there is no reason to `return` anything within your `frame` function, as well. You can only `return` a single value from a function *(could be an Array or Object with multiple properties)* and `setInterval`'s function argument doesn't need to receive a `return` value.

Comment: Yes, I figured that the frames overlapping had something to do with the score getting so high. I am just not sure how to resolve that. The code suggested had the same effect on the animation. I've since tried e.stopPropagation and adding once:true to the click event to stop it from bubbling up and down, but that didn't seem to get at the issue. The fact that I searching a resolution online isn't very fruitful makes me think that there must be an easier way to click on a moving animation.